# AFOAuthcredential and storing credentials

Tags: objective-c, get, afnetworking

Using AFOAuthcredential for storing the accessToken in my singleton.
I use this line of code in my singleton to store it.

```
[AFOAuthCredential storeCredential:newCredential withIdentifier:self.serviceProviderIdentifier];
```

My question is, when im in exampleViewController.h and i want to get the token to make a GET call. How do i retrieve this Credential.

In my viewWillAppear in my exampleViewController.h I call

```
theSingleton *singleton = [[theSingleton alloc] init];

AFOAuthCredential *credential = [AFOAuthCredential retrieveCredentialWithIdentifier:@"self.serviceProviderIdentifier"];
NSString *accessToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", credential.accessToken];
```

I want to store the accessToken in the app until it is expired, and then it will refresh it.  My question is, how do i call the retriveCredential from other parts of my app and get he valid token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Call to `retrieveCredentialsWithIdentifier` from anywhere inside your code should return the same token as long as you pass in the same identifier.